# Can I attach a photograph to a bitcoin?

Tags: wallet, development, namecoin

Let's say I'm a photographer, and I want to sell my photograph as if it were fine art, so there's a limited edition print, or even just one which has been signed by me and can be thought of as genuine.

Now, I know that there will be copies of the picture itself, because there's always easy ways, but how can I attach my photograph to a bitcoin or a portion of a bitcoin and thereby add value to the bitcoin and value to my phtotographs?

I  know colour coins are in the works, but lets turn it around. A bitcoin has no substance right? But what if instead of a wallet with a number inside, you could have a stack of bitcoins each with different pictures attached? It would be like a personal art gallery, cover flow with money.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: That's exactly what colored coins are for.

Answer (score 1):

So you are asking if it is possible to store a huge chunk of data in an tx output what worth 100000000 satoshi, right? Yes, it is possible but you have to pay really big fee to store your picture in the blockchain on millions of computers.

Comment: Great, OK, so not ideal: but have you any idea how big the fee would be? Let's imagine storing the equivalent of a digital Mona-Lisa and say... a Warhol Campbell's Soup print. Just for argument's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Namecoin is better than Bitcoin for this.

Here's a project that supports uploading files onto and downloading files from the namecoin blockchain:

https://github.com/runn1ng/namecoin-files